# How to speed up this code about a triple integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

How to speed up this code? It's unbelievably slow!!! My solution with pen and paper is faster.

```
Clear[R, h];
Integrate[
 Integrate[
  Integrate[1, {z, h, Sqrt[R^2 - x^2 - y^2]}, 
   Assumptions -> Element[y, Reals]]
  , {y, -Sqrt[R^2 - h^2 - x^2], Sqrt[R^2 - h^2 - x^2]}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]
 , {x, -Sqrt[R^2 - h^2], Sqrt[R^2 - h^2]}, 
 Assumptions -> 
  Element[R, Reals] && R > 0 && Element[h, Reals] && 0 < h < R, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> $\frac{1}{3}\pi (h-R)^2 (h+2 R)$

It's a triple integral over a spherical cap.

I have got the solution, but... I can't understand why *Mathematica* is so slow.

Comment: @corey I use 3 Integrals, because of the documentation (It´s bad). And the results are different. With 1 Integral I can´t use the result as function(but it´s fast :-) ) and With 3 Integrals of go weel except the slow. With one integral I have problems with the Assumptions.

Comment: Why not use cylindrical coordinates? `Integrate[r, {z, h, R}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, Sqrt[R^2 - z^2]}]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A timing analysis. Each integration was performed on a fresh kernel.

The OP's code:

```
Integrate[
  Integrate[
   Integrate[1, {z, h, Sqrt[R^2 - x^2 - y^2]}, Assumptions -> Element[y, Reals]],
    {y, -Sqrt[R^2 - h^2 - x^2], Sqrt[R^2 - h^2 - x^2]}, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]],
     {x, -Sqrt[R^2 - h^2], Sqrt[R^2 - h^2]}, Assumptions -> Element[R, Reals] && R > 0 && Element[h, Reals] && 0 < h < R, 
  GenerateConditions -> False] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {326.12, 1/3 π (h - R)^2 (h + 2 R)}

Reformulating it is much faster:

```
Integrate[1,
 {x, -Sqrt[R^2 - h^2], Sqrt[R^2 - h^2]},
 {y, -Sqrt[R^2 - h^2 - x^2], Sqrt[R^2 - h^2 - x^2]},
 {z, h, Sqrt[R^2 - x^2 - y^2]}, 
  Assumptions -> {x, y, z} ∈ Reals && R > 0 && 0 < h < R] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {80.5937, 1/3 π (h - R)^2 (h + 2 R)}

It could be sped up with `Boole`; there should be no difference between `x > h`, `y > h` and `z > h` due to the symmetry, but:

```
Integrate[
  Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < R^2 && x > h], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
   {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> R > 0 && 0 < h < R] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {11.8003, 1/3 π (h - R)^2 (h + 2 R)}

```
Integrate[
  Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < R^2 && y > h], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> R > 0 && 0 < h < R] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {106.909, 1/3 π (h - R)^2 (h + 2 R)}

```
Integrate[
  Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < R^2 && z > h], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
   {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> R > 0 && 0 < h < R] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {86.4646, 1/3 π (h - R)^2 (h + 2 R)}

**EDIT:** The timing differences in the last three integrals are not due to changing the names of the variables `var` (i.e., $x\leftrightarrow y\leftrightarrow z$ in the `var > h` part), as could be suspected at first glance, but due to the order of integration; in `Integrate[f[x,y,z], {x, ....}, {y, ....}, {z, ....}]` the integration over `z` is performed first, and over `x` last. The first (among the last three) integral is the fastest as the integration over the *vertical* direction through the cap is performed last $-$ i.e., one sums the stacked full circles. In other cases, the consecutive integrations are performed over regions not so regular, which requires MMA to take more time.